# execute command in ViewModel from Mouse event

Tags: c#, wpf

Very basic mvvm cross question...

I am creating a WPF UI and want to make an image map. I have my path objects defined and now want to hook up a command from the view model to the mouse up event on the path.

Initially I thought it would just be a case of adding the event handler and calling the command from there, but the code behind does not have a reference to the view model because of IoC, and I cannot see any way of directly using a xaml property.

Comment: depending on to which control you want to bind, you might be able to use EventsToCommand and directly bind it in your xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<Path Data="M 80,200 A 100,50 45 1 0 100,50" >
    <Path.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding MyPathCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </Path.InputBindings>
</Path>
```

Comment: Perfect. Still learning what nesting properties like this exist. Do you have any handy web references for these less obvious xaml properties?

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t… sorry